# Is it safe to use a API with the Phonegap?

Tags: cordova

Let's say I want to show a twitter stream or photos from flickr. Those api's require a key to work.

Can I use this in the phonegap? Or is this unsafe cause people can get the api key that way?

Answer (score 1):

Both ways store Auth tokens in similar locations, it is the same level of security if coded correctly:

Native: Preferences, Sqlite
Cordova: LocalStorage or Sqlite

Normally API services always work with a Oauth protocol that avoids store password user into the device but only store a revocable token only to be used in that app.

Of course you can encrypt SQLLite with a Second Key that also has to be stored somewhere into de device.... Simply another layer of security that normally it is not necessary, but you can code it both in native and cordova.

Comment: That is exactly how I see it, *if* you decide to add encryption of the token as an extra layer, you will always need to store the encryption key somewhere. Native as well as hybrid applications suffer from the same problem. Only Exception is iOS, where you can use the keychain, which is encrypted with the device PIN-Code itself.